# Test if chapter is a valid command

Tags: conditionals

I want to test if the class supports chapters. However with the package `titlesec` the check for the command `\chapter` fails because it is always defined:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\ifcsdef{chapter}{chapter is defined}{chapter is NOT defined}

\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

This prints out: `chapter is defined`

I could test before loading `titlesec` and create a boolean that I test, but I would rather want to test it at any point of the document with a single check. How could I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of `etoolbox`:

> `\ifdef{<control sequence>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>   Expands to `<true>` if the `<control sequence>` is deﬁned, and to `<false>` otherwise. Note that control sequences will be considered as defined even if their meaning is `\relax`. This command is a LaTeX wrapper for the e-TeX primitive `\ifdefined`.
>
> `\ifundef{<control sequence>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>   Expands to `<true>` if the `<control sequence>` is undeﬁned, and to `<false>` otherwise. Apart from reversing the logic of the test, this command also differs from `\ifdef` in that commands will be considered as undefined if their meaning is `\relax`.
>
> `\ifcsdef{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>   Similar to `\ifdef` except that it takes a control sequence name as its first 
>   argument. This command is a LaTeX wrapper for the e-TeX primitive `\ifcsname`.
>
> `\ifcsundef{<csname>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>   Similar to `\ifundef` except that it takes a control sequence name as its first argument. This command may be used as a drop-in replacement for the `\@ifundefined` test in the LaTeX kernel.

Thus you should use `\ifcsundef` (reversing the two arguments):

```
\ifcsundef{chapter}{chapter is NOT defined}{chapter is defined}
```

or

```
\ifundef\chapter{chapter is NOT defined}{chapter is defined}
```

The `titlesec` package performs the test `\@ifundefined{chapter}{...}{...}` and so `\chapter` becomes equivalent to `\relax`.

Answer (score 3):

With a simple `\ifChapter`

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifChapter
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\Chapterfalse}{\Chaptertrue}
\makeatletter
\ifChapter \usepackage{titlesec} \fi
\begin{document}
\ifChapter \chapter{title} \else \section{title}\fi
\ifChapter chapter is defined \else chapter is NOT defined \fi
\end{document}
```