# A \cite{} as name for a chapter header

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, chapters

I'm writing a document where each chapter is a reading record of a paper. So I want the name of the chapter to be the title of the paper, and the header of the chapter to be the short citation of the bib reference.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{ECM.bib}
@ARTICLE{greenwade93,
  author  = "George Greenwade",
  title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
  year    = "1993",
  journal = "TUGBoat",
  volume  = "14",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\addbibresource{ECM.bib}

\usepackage{forest, philex}

\begin{document}
\chapter[\cite{greenwade93}]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
\sectionmark{version for header}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

But as you can see, the header prints the bib key instead of the real short citation.
Is there a way to print `Greenwade, 1993`, instead of `greenwade93`?

Comment: Just an idea: is it possible to "memorise" the result of the \cite{} inside a string variable?

Comment: The problem is that the optional argument to `\chapter` (the one in square brackets) is uppercased, that leads to the argument to the cite command also being uppercased and subsequently `biblatex` trying to find the entry key "GREENWADE93" (all uppercase letter).

Comment: A work-around would be `\newcommand{\citegreen}{\cite{greenwade93}}` and then `\chapter[\protect\citegreen]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}` *or* `\DeclareRobustCommand{\citegreen}{\cite{greenwade93}}` and `\chapter[\citegreen]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}` as per [UK TeX FAQ: Case-changing oddities](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange).

Comment: The [UK] TeX FAQ as mentioned in @moewe's comment has moved.  The reference is now at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@moewe has already explained why this happens. A package free solution (well, almost package free) is to remove `\MakeUppercase` from the definition of `\chaptermark` (which I insist was a design error to begin with):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{greenwade93,
  author  = "George Greenwade",
  title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
  year    = "1993",
  journal = "TUGBoat",
  volume  = "14",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{forest, philex,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chaptermark}{\MakeUppercase}{\@firstofone}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter[\cite{greenwade93}]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
\sectionmark{version for header}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Using `\patchcmd` is easier than doing

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter.\ %
      \fi
    \fi
    #1%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother
```

where I copied the definition from `book.cls` and removed the dreaded `\MakeUppercase`.

Answer (score 6):

### Update

If you are using a current version of the LaTeX kernel, the case changing code will automatically leave `\cite` alone.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{greenwade93,
  author  = "George Greenwade",
  title   = "The {Comprehensive} {TeX} {Archive} {Network} ({CTAN})",
  year    = "1993",
  journal = "TUGBoat",
  volume  = "14",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  \chapter[\cite{greenwade93}]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
  Lorem
  \newpage
  Ipsum
\end{document}
```

If you are using a command that the case changer does not leave alone (e.g. `\autocite` or `\textcite`), you can tell it to with

```
\AddToNoCaseChangeList{\autocite \textcite}
```

---

### Old Answer

The problem you experience is because the optional argument to `\chapter` is passed to `\MakeUppercase`. That will cause the `\cite{greenwade93}` command to come out as `\cite{GREENWADE93}`, but of course `biblatex` cannot find the entry to that cite key.

The [List of TeX FAQs: Case-changing oddities](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-casechange) actually describes several remedies for that situation.

You could define a helper command `\citegreen`

```
\newcommand{\citegreen}{\cite{greenwade93}}
```

And `\protect` the call to `\citegreen` in `\chapter`

```
\chapter[\protect\citegreen]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
```

Alternatively, `\citegreen` can be made robust by definition

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\citegreen}{\cite{greenwade93}}
\chapter[\citegreen]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
```

---

A solution without a helper macro is to use David Carlisle's [`textcase`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package with the `overload` option. This will replace `\MakeUppercase` by a slightly more sophisticated `\MakeTextUppercase` macro that deals with the commands above as expected.

Load the package

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

You can just use

```
\chapter[\cite{greenwade93}]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
```

then.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{greenwade93,
  author  = "George Greenwade",
  title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
  year    = "1993",
  journal = "TUGBoat",
  volume  = "14",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
  \chapter[\cite{greenwade93}]{\citetitle{greenwade93}}
  Lorem
  \newpage
  Ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I ensure that `\AddToNoCaseChangeList` is available as a command? I have two PCs, and this answer works on one of them but not the other (*undefined control sequence*). Both have TeX Live 2022 installed and are trying to compile the same project.

Comment: @Mew Tricky. `\AddToNoCaseChangeList` is part of the LaTeX kernel. If one of your systems is too old to have it, I don't think you can easily code an alternative. You can try to use `\ifundef` to avoid the error (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95734/35864), but then you need to keep in mind that things will probably only work properly on the newer system that actually has the command.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with TeX's versioning system, but I was under the impression that versions were stable year-over-year. Is it possible that `\AddToNoCaseChangeList` was added somewhere in 2022, and that I missed it by a couple of months on only one of my installations?

Comment: @Mew With TeX Live the binaries are stable for each version, but packages (and the LaTeX kernel) may change. (With MikTeX not even binaries are the same, they can get updated year-round.) Depending on how you installed your systems and when you last updated them, you may have different versions. TeX Live 2023 is out now, so if you install it on both systems and update now, you should get matching versions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but if you use uppercase only in the refname, it works:

```
@ARTICLE{GREENWADE93,
  author  = "George Greenwade",
  title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
  year    = "1993",
  journal = "TUGBoat",
  volume  = "14",
  number  = "3",
  pages   = "342--351"
}
```

and

```
\chapter[\cite{GREENWADE93}]{\citetitle{GREENWADE93}}
```

I found it, because my log gives me:

```
Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                GREENWADE93
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it also works for me. But for other reasons, I can't change the whole list of entries of my bibliography database. So I can't really use this trick :/

Comment: If you have a "static" bib-file it's a very easy regex. In case you can need it: You can search for pattern `(^@.*?\{)(.*?,)` and replace it with `\1\U\2`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I don't know what you mean by "static" bib-file (like I always use the same file, which is not modified?), and I don't know what a regex is. And your pattern symbols are chinese for me :)

Comment: With "static" I mean you're working on your bibfile per hand and it doesn't get created dynamically by a program etc.
Then you can use regex as a workaround (- so this is no latex solution). With using the patterns I wrote you can easily make all your refnames uppercase. Look for a text editor which features Regex, like Notepad++. The rest the internet will tell you.

Comment: Oh ok. So no, I don't have a static bib-file. I'm not sure yet if it's the final version, so I can modify it by hand. So your solution may be useful. But I would prefer not to have to modify it, in case I have to generate it again.